# Find when a GitHub project forked from it's GitHub fork parent

Tags: git, github

I want to know what commit a specific project was forked from its parent so I can fork from the same commit number.

How can I achieve this?

More specifically, I want to know the commit number of when

https://github.com/superbitcoin/SuperBitcoin

was forked from

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin

Comment: would https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base help. Note that it is not exactly what you are asking, if the forked project was updated, but since you mentioned "I can fork from the same commit number" it could be what you really need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First clone one of the repositories:

```
git clone https://github.com/superbitcoin/SuperBitcoin.git
```

The superbitcoin/SuperBitcoin repository is your `origin`. Now add the other repository as a second remote and `fetch` its commits:

```
cd SuperBitcoin
git remote add upstream https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git
git fetch upstream
```

Now you can use `merge-base`, as suggested by max630 in the comments:

```
git merge-base origin/master upstream/master
```

Note that you must compare specific branches.

This gives `c2704ec98a1b7b35b6a7c1b6b26a3f16d44e8880`, which is the last common commit between the two branches. You can see this commit in [each](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/c2704ec98a1b7b35b6a7c1b6b26a3f16d44e8880) [repository](https://github.com/superbitcoin/SuperBitcoin/commit/c2704ec98a1b7b35b6a7c1b6b26a3f16d44e8880).